# Entity Framework, Textbox saves to Database as "" instead of Nothing (NULL)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

In the program I've been writing, when a Textbox has an empty string in it, it will save to the Database as an empty string instead of NULL.

```
    Using DB As New wotcDB
        Dim u = (From t In DB.interview_ltu Where t.CONTROL = CONTROL And t.CLIENTCODE = CLIENTCODE).FirstOrDefault
        If u Is Nothing Then
            Dim i As New interview_ltu
            i.CONTROL = CONTROL
            i.CLIENTCODE = CLIENTCODE
            i.LTUnemp2Years = cboLTUnemp2Years.DBValue
            i.LTUnempExhast26wks = cboLTUnempExhast26wks.DBValue
            i.LTUComments = txtLTUnemployedCMT.Text
            i.LTUnempStart = txtLTUnempStart.DateValue
            i.LTUnempStop = txtLTUnempStop.DateValue
            DB.interview_ltu.Add(i)
            DB.SaveChanges()
        Else
            u.LTUnemp2Years = cboLTUnemp2Years.DBValue
            u.LTUnempExhast26wks = cboLTUnempExhast26wks.DBValue
            u.LTUComments = txtLTUnemployedCMT.Text
            u.LTUnempStart = txtLTUnempStart.DateValue
            u.LTUnempStop = txtLTUnempStop.DateValue
            DB.SaveChanges()
        End If
    End Using
```

I've been doing this complicated step where I check String.IsNullorEmpty on each one, but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary especially considering that questions related to this on Google imply that the opposite is true and people are trying to get an empty string instead of a NULL.

So how do I get Text boxes to save as NULL instead of empty strings?

Edit:

I've added this code to my Context;

```
Private Const StringType As String = "String"
Private Const SavingState As EntityState = EntityState.Added Or EntityState.Modified
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
    'when using on ObjectContext replace 'objectContext' with 'this',
    'and override SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) instead:

    Dim objectContext = CType(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    Dim savingEntries = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(SavingState)

    For Each entry As Object In savingEntries
        Dim curValues = entry.CurrentValues
        Dim fieldMetadata = curValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata
        Dim stringFields = fieldMetadata.Where(Function(f) f.FieldType.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name = StringType)
        For Each stringField As Object In stringFields
            Dim ordinal = stringField.Ordinal
            Dim curValue = TryCast(curValues(ordinal), String)
            If Not curValue Is Nothing AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(curValue) Then ' AndAlso curValue.All(Char.IsWhiteSpace) Then
                curValues.SetValue(ordinal, Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()
    'SaveChanges(options) on ObjectContext
End Function
```

When it reaches "For Each entry As Object In savingEntries" it just jumps over to the end since it doesn't pick any entries up. I've tried to change the inputs. No success.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the links below. This may help

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6340557)

[Link2](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/09/01/entity-framework-save-empty-strings-as-null-in-your-db/)

Comment: I went ahead and converted the code to VB, but when it saves it just skips the chunk that would turn an empty string into nothing.

Comment: Actually I have no idea in VB :(. The C# code provided in links above to override the `SaveChanges` method works for me. what i can suggest you  to use some online C# to VB converter.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  You should at least provide some summary of the information given in the links in case the links are ever rendered invalid.