# SQL Server- not permit empty string and have null instead (similar to Oracle)

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, is there a way to have the database act similar to Oracle in the way that an empty string = NULL?

I don't want to permit empty strings in my database and want these to purely be NULLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no such setting. Instead you could handle this in your data access tier ([Entity Framework example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119615/is-there-an-option-to-make-entity-framework-revert-empty-strings-to-null)) or in a table trigger.

You can use a check constraint to prevent empty strings from being inserted, thus forcing the client to handle the empty-to-null conversion.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Table1_Col1] CHECK (Col1 <> '')
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been thinking about it and I don't think it is going to be an issue as I am using SSIS to pull data from Oracle, so I can't see how the values could come back as empty strings anway.